# How do I know which maven package contains the class I am going to use?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

For example, if I am new to spring mvc framework, I follow a tutorial and need to use DispatcherServlet. So I come to  [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework), search for spring, comes out many dependency candidate:

spring-context, spring-web, spring-core, ....

How do I know which of them contains the class I wanted: DispatcherServlet, without searching on Google first?

Comment: These things can't be known until either you have worked on them, or search them on the maven repo.

Comment: The spring projects (http://spring.io/projects) page for the project will often tell you, or point you in the direction of which maven artefacts you need.  If the project you want isn't listed, its usually a sub project of something else, Spring Web is a sub project of Spring framework, and its Maven coordinates can be found from a link on the Spring framework page.

Comment: How can you find something without searching? Luck?? Nah, better to rely on searching, don't you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can go to the [Advanced search page of Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch) which gives you the choice to search `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `packaging` and `classifier` or for a `Classname`.

[image]

Comment: Getting a 404 now

Answer (score 2):

If you run a repository manager (e.g., nexus, artefactory) it will have a classname search on its advanced search option.

Or you can search here
https://mvnrepository.com

I expect, eclipse, idea or netbeans ide to offer search too.  If you click on the class and open its definition (ctrl b in idea, F3  in eclipse, the ide open the appropriate src jar)

Comment: This is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

A tip, if you are using IntelliJ IDEA is to write the static type of the class you need inside the IDE and select 'Add Maven dependency' (can be accessed from the menu you open with ALT+Enter). Then the IDE will find the right Maven dependency for you and add it automatically to your pom.xml.